# Java Regex to find whether string contains sql injection characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find whether string has SQL injection characters like ',",\b,\r,\n,\t.

I am using the below pattern, but it is not giving the expected result.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: Why don't you use approved patterns, e.g. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.

Comment: Or just use `PreparedStatements` instead of concatinating user input?

Comment: sql injection should be a thing of past **if** you are using right tools (e.g. as Coron suggested)

Comment: I am using Prepared statement only . Still if input contains ',",\r,\n i need to throw error message

Comment: if `['"\r\n]` then throw msg.